# Transponse and inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have two lower diagonal matrices L and M
If I have $(L^TL)^{-1} (M^TM) = I$
where $L^T$ is the transpose of L
can I say

$(LM^{-1})^T (LM^{-1}) = I$

why? and using what lemma or theorem..

Thanks

Comment: In `LaTeX` use `\top` for the transpose, like `A^\top=`$A^\top$.

Comment: @ja72 Why? Or I mean, why would one care just in this question? I've never heard of a *standard* notation for transpose and saw at least five different styles (except `\top`) in SE. And this is the first time I see somebody complaining about it :D

Comment: Read this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30632). The $^T$ is italicized which is a no-no for operators, it is too big and it is ugly.

Comment: ...and, as also mentioned in that post, opinion-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

$(L^TL)^{-1} (M^TM) = I$ implies $L^TL = M^TM $ .

$(LM^{-1})^T (LM^{-1})  = {M^{-1}}^T L^T L M^{-1}$.

Combining them gives  $(LM^{-1})^T (LM^{-1}) =  {M^{-1}}^T M^T M M^{-1} =I$.

Comment: Thanks you are asuming what I want to get at. I am going to go backwards. why does ${M^{-1}}^T M^T M M^{-1} =I$ ?

Comment: I think I know why? ${M^{-1}}^T$ = ${M^{T}}^{-1}$

Comment: @user1510863: or you could do ${M^{-1}}^T M^T =(MM^{-1})^T$

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see where being "lower diagonal" (lower triangular?) comes into play, but this should be a pretty simple manipulation:  Just use that inverses are unique (i.e., if $A^{-1} B = I$, then $A = B$), that multiplication is associative (that is, $A(BC) = (AB)C$) and the property that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

Comment: Thanks, I know these properties already..

Answer (score 0):

$$ (L M^{-1})^\top (L M^{-1}) = 1 $$
$$ M^{-\top} L^\top L M^{-1} = 1 $$
$$ M^{-\top} (L^\top L) M^{-1} = 1 $$
$$ M^{-\top} (M^\top M) M^{-1} = 1 $$

since $(L^\top L)^{-1} (M^\top M)=1 \} L^\top L = M^\top M$

Comment: Use $I$ for the identity.

Comment: IMHO $1$ is far clearer (especially when I use $I$ for inertia) since $1\,A = A$ regardless of the size of $A$. Sometimes I might use $[1]$ or $1_{N×M}$ for example also.

Comment: IMHO $1_{N\times M}$ might be more confusing than $I$, especially when some people use similar notation to denote a zero matrix.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `N×M` zero matrix be $0_{N×M}$? Why would anyone use a $1$ for a zero matrix? It seems so counter intuitive.

Comment: $1_{N\times N}$ can be read by some (especially for those from a Matlab background) as the matrix of all $1$s

Comment: @ja72 similar $\neq$ same